# How to use the New Relay in Azure

Tags: azure, integration, azureservicebus, relay, azure-servicebusrelay

Azure recently separated the Relay from Service Bus name space. Under the new relay we have WCF Relays and Hybrid Connections. They are urging people to use the new Relay, but i couldn't find any nuget packages that supports new Relay. There is a nuget package for Hybrid Connection under the name relay, but it doesn't support WCF Relay created nuder new Relay namespace. i was wondering if i was wrong or if this is infact the case. if anyone can confirm it would be really helpful.

Regards,
Vishnu

Comment: You should be able to use the new namespace with the same SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Azure recently separated the Relay from Service Bus name space. Under the new relay we have WCF Relays and Hybrid Connections. They are urging people to use the new Relay, but i couldn't find any nuget packages that supports new Relay. There is a nuget package for Hybrid Connection under the name relay, but it doesn't support WCF Relay created nuder new Relay namespace.

As you said, Azure Relay has two features: Hybrid Connections and WCF Relays. If you’d like to use Service Bus WCF Relay, you could refer to [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/service-bus-dotnet-how-to-use-relay) that shared us a sample written in C# and use the WCF API with extensions contained in the Service Bus assembly, and it just requires Service Bus NuGet package.